# Encrypt a PDF file in the command line using pdftk command

Tags: perl

i am tiring to perform PDF file encryption using pdftk and installed the dependency modules of PDF::Tk [Perl integration for the pdf toolkit (pdftk)] , but getting error as mentioned below. Can any one please help me in resolving the below issue.

Source code: test.pl

```
use PDF::Tk;
system(pdftk input.pdf output outPDF.pdf owner_pw foopass) or die "Error!!!!!!!!!!\n";
```

output:

```
Can't locate object method "pdftk" via package "input" (perhaps you forgot to load "input"?) at test.pl line 2.
```

Comment: You get that error because you're not quoting the parameters to `system()`, but as @miguel-prz points out, you shouldn't be using `system()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `PDF::Tk` module functions instead the `system`. `PDF::Tk` is a wrapper over the `pdftk` utility, so using `system` is the topic it avoids:

```
use PDF::Tk;
my $doc=PDF::Tk->new();
$doc->call_pdftk('input.pdf', 'outPDF.pdf', 'owner_pw', 'foopass');
```

**Note:** The PDF::Tk constructor could be used to set the pdftk binary. It defaults value is "/usr/bin/pdftk"

```
my $doc=PDF::Tk->new({pdftk=>'/other/path/to/bin/pdftk'});
```

Comment: Modified code as per your guidence, but getting error as "Can't find executablable /usr/bin/pdftk at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/PDF/Tk.pm line 19.". Please guide me in overcoming the above error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. case 1: Do i need to add "my $doc=PDF::Tk->new({pdftk=>'/other/path/to/bin/pdftk'});" this line in my .pl file replacement of "my $doc=PDF::Tk->new();" case 2: Do i need to modify PDF/Tk.pm file. In case 1: still getting the same error as of previous comment.

Comment: @user142847 use case 1, what you must search where is your pdftk binary tool, and then change "/other/path/to/bin/pdftk" by the real path on your system

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i got my pdftk binary file path and passed path information to pdftk=>'/apps/free/pdftk/' and tried running it, getting error as "pdftk input.pdf owner_pw foopass outPDF.pdf failed: -1 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/PDF/Tk.pm line 73.". please help  me resolving it.